# Can I order hard-boiled eggs baked in a oven used only for eggs. How about in a non-kosher kitchen?

Tags: cooking-bishul, bishul-akum

Is one allowed to eat hard "baked" eggs (not boiled in a pot) from a non kosher juice bar that only serves juices and eggs. Their oven is only used for eggs, as they don't serve any other food.

Comment: welcome to mi yodeya Gavriel. I don't know why, but I remember that there was minhagim about hard eggs.

Answer (score 2):

no, because there would be no way to verify such a claim in a non kosher kitchen. We don't rely on the word of non-Jews for koshrus.

Comment: That's not true. We rely on their word if we know they could get in serious trouble if they were caught lying. You can buy certified vegan snacks at any market without a hecsher

Comment: @Aaron, no not true. First of all vegan needs a hechsher b/c of bugs and secondly no we don't trust them. This is why part of having a hechsher involves having a mashgiach present. We don't doesn't rely on the word of someone who isn't obligated to keep kosher for kosher supervision.

Comment: @dude some vegan stuff has grape juice in it too. But Aarons point on the whole is correct. It would depend on the specific vegan product.

Comment: @Dude A vegan place would risk losing vegan status if they had a high content of bugs in their food. Often times they are more scrupulous than hecsher agencies who often times only show up once a year.

Comment: @Dude and why do they show up only once a year? Because like I said earlier, even hecsher agencies trust them when they know they risk to lose a lot by lying.

Comment: @Aaron Often times though they are less scrupulous than Kashrut agencies about bugs. Again, it really depends on the agency and the vegetable and bug in question. General rules about vegan orgs which permitting them all are about as silly as those which forbid them all.

Comment: @DoubleAA Agreed. But Dude didn't seem to have a middle ground. So the best way to create one was to highlight the positive. The Rabbis of the Talmud found ways to eat in the inns of the goyim during their travels. It seems silly to be so strict that you wouldn't be able to eat at chazals table.

Comment: @Aaron Chazal lived at a time when food production involved mixing 3 raw ingrediants in a metal pot. It seems silly to compare the two even roughly.

Comment: @DoubleAA we are discussing a situation in which the food production involves only two ingredients. So if you ask me it seems like an excellent comparison

Comment: @Aaron No we're talking about vegan hashgachas. I didn't complain about the egg case

Comment: @DoubleAA My comment about the Rabbis was me switching to the overall topic of trusting non jewish chefs when we clearly know what's going on. Such as with hardboiled eggs that are cooked there on the spot.

Comment: @DoubleAA Why is Aaron's point on the whole correct? (that you can eat certified vegan snacks without a hechsher -- seems like a stretch to me) (other than the argument that kashrus has gotten a lot stricter than it needs to be, which is maybe an ok argument, but with few practical implications)

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed only uses for eggs then there is no worry about it being not kosher in terms of ingredients. However it still falls under the category of bishul akum. So if you were to ask if it was okay for you to turn on their oven, or be a part of the cooking process in some way, then it would be permissible to eat.

Comment: Bishul akum applies to hard-boiled eggs?

Comment: @paquda see YD 113:14

Comment: @paquda    Yes, all egg dishes.